# Print <li> lists based on unique column values

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to print few lists based on unique column values with the below function:

```
<?php
function echoList($country) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$country`");
$previousClass = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $thisClass = $row['class'];
  if($thisClass != $previousClass) {
        echo '<h3>' . $thisClass.'</h3>';
  }
  echo '<ul>';
  $id = $row['id'];
  echo '<li><a href="' . $country . '/'. $id . '">' . $id . '</a></li>';
  echo '</ul>';  
  $previousClass = $thisClass;
}
}
```

Table is something like this:

```
id,class,description
1,B,description1
2,B,description2
3,C,description3
4,B,description4
5,B,description5
```

but this is repeating and not grouping in same UL, im trying to group but Im not figuring out how to do, 
what i like is to print in this way:

```
<h3>B</h3>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<h3>C</h3>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

if anyone of you can help to this one, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function echoList($country) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$country` order by class, id");
$previousClass = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $thisClass = $row['class'];
  if($thisClass != $previousClass) {
        if ($previousClass) { echo '</ul>';  }
        echo '<h3>' . $thisClass.'</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
  }

  $id = $row['id'];
  echo '<li><a href="' . $country . '/'. $id . '">' . $id . '</a></li>';

  $previousClass = $thisClass;
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Something like this. Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated.